# Search for similar (non-exact-duplicate) files in a directory

Tags: search

Is there a command in Linux to recursively search a directory and find files that are similar to each other in content (name doesn't matter)? Perhaps using the levenshtein string distance.

`fdupes` is not a good fit because I need to look for *inexact* matches.

Comment: There is `fslint`, `fdupes` and probably others. Google "ubuntu how to find duplicate files".

Comment: _non-exact-duplicate_.